# In Java selenium webdriver - Is there a way to make alternate columns as header of a webtable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a Webtable with four columns with the structure be like

[Webtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cPZ9.png)

I have to iterate throw each rows in the webtable and create an output in this format:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7eBD.png)

And output should be written to an Excel file.

Could anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Post the markup and any code you've tried.  To create the Excel file I recommend POI: https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Code trials? Relevant HTML?

Comment: Added HTML tr>
<td><table cellspacing="5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="textLabel"><label>RdwLength:</label></td>
<td class="text"><span class="text">8034</span></td>
<td class="textLabel"><label>CompanyCode:</label></td>
<td class="text"><span class="text">101</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="textLabel"><label>SortCtlInd:</label></td>
<td class="text"><span class="text"> </span></td>
<td class="textLabel"><label>MasterId:</label></td>
<td class="text"><span class="text">FP16000367</span></td>
</tr>